# Tool tips on cells not embedded in instances of NSMatrix

Tags: interface-builder

I get this warning when building, in Xcode 8.0 beta 6.
It is listed under “Unsupported configuration”.
When I click on it in the Issue Navigator, the file Main.storyboard gets selected, but no element inside seems to get selected, giving no clue as to where the problem lies.

I don’t understand it, and I don’t know what to look for.
I tried clearing all tooltips, but the warning stays.
What does it mean, and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the Tool Tip from Button Cell and adding it to Push Button. That should help.

[image: Button Cell]

Comment: How can I “remove” the tool tip? As I said, I did clear every tool tip field through the Identity inspector, and still get three such warnings.

Comment: Can you upload the smallest possible Xcode project that reproduces the problem?